# Convert from single column to multiple Column in sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-columns

[image]
[image]

i have tried with below code. but i didnt get ouput as per multiple column.

```
select Name=stuff((select ','+ 
 name from Input t1 WHERE t1.Name=t2.name for xml path('')),1,9,''),NAME 
 =stuff((select ','+ 
 name from Input t1 WHERE t1.Name=t2.name for xml path('')),1,1,'')FROM 
 Input T2
 GROUP BY NAME
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have separated the character and numeric parts of the given string in CTE and used a simple group by and sum clause on that.

```
;With CTE
As
(
    Select 
        Left(Names, 1) As String,
        SUBSTRING(Names, 2, Len(Names) - 1) As Number
    From SeparateColumns
)
Select 
    String,
    Sum(Cast(Number As Int)) As SumOfDigits
From CTE
Group By String
Order By String;
```

Comment: **[Your answer's idea is same as mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427869/convert-from-single-column-to-multiple-column-in-sql-server/47427980#47427980)**

Comment: Yeah, I know, what a coincidence. Jinx :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `PATINDEX()` with `SUBSTRING()` function if `names` always in this specified format

```
select A.CHAR [Strings], SUM(CAST(A.VALUE AS INT)) [Sum] from 
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING(Name, 1, PATINDEX('%[^A-Z]%', Name)-1) [CHAR], SUBSTRING(Name, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Name), len(Name)) [VALUE] FROM <table>
) a GROUP BY A.CHAR
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `names` column is always in the specified format, then use **`LEFT`** function to extract the character part and **`RIGHT`** function to extract the digits part and use these two in the sub-query and use **`GROUP BY`** clause and **`SUM`** function.

**Query**

```
select t.col_a as [string character], 
sum(cast(t.col_b as int)) as [sum of digits] from(
    select left(names, 1) as col_a,
    right(names, len(names) - 1) as col_b
    from [your_table_name]
) t
group by t.col_a;
```

**[Find a example here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/761630/convert-from-single-column-to-multiple-column-in-sql-server)**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you will have single character in your column, the following code works

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_SPLIT
(VALUE VARCHAR(25))


INSERT INTO #TEMP_SPLIT
SELECT 'A10'
UNION
SELECT 'B20'
UNION
SELECT 'A30'
UNION
SELECT 'B40'
UNION
SELECT 'A10'
UNION
SELECT 'C1'


SELECT c, sum(tot) 
FROM
     (
        SELECT SUBSTRING(VALUE,1,1) c ,CONVERT(FLOAT,SUBSTRING(VALUE,2,LEN  (VALUE)-1)) Tot
         FROM #TEMP_SPLIT

      )T     
 GROUP BY C

 DROP TABLE #TEMP_SPLIT
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's simple solution using subquery and `group by` clause:

```
select [StringChar], SUM([Number]) from (
    select SUBSTRING(Names, 1, 1) as [StringChar],
           convert(int, SUBSTRING(Names, 2, LEN(Names))) as [Number]
    from [Input]
) as a group by [StringChar]
```